# angular 2 with modules from angular 1

Tags: angularjs, typescript, fullcalendar, angular, angular-ui-grid

Using angularjs 2 with typescript don't know how to use angular 1 modules like ui-grid or fullcalendar.
I can add module ui-grid with typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the migration guide: 
[AngularJS 1 to Angular 2 Upgrade Strategy](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xvBZoFuNq9hsgRhPPZOJC-Z48AHEbIBPlOCBTSD8m0Y)

, and specifically this section: "Wrapping: AngularJS 1 to Angular 2"

You might also find this post useful: [Angular 1 and Angular 2 integration: the path to seamless upgrade](http://angularjs.blogspot.se/2015/08/angular-1-and-angular-2-coexistence.html)

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG provides FullCalendar integration and a DataTable, code is open source so you can review how the integration is done. DataTable is native though. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule